# senfing POST in fetch return null

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend, fetch

I want to learn how fetch works. Backend is very simple

```
<?php
    print_r(json_encode($_POST['test']));
```

And I created this fetch

```
fetch('http://localhost/test.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        test: 'test'
    })
})
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => console.log(data))
```

All the time this code return null in console.log. Where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

## Strings and Fetch

If you POST a string using `fetch` it will default to sending it with a `Content-Type: text/plain` header.

Plain text isn't JSON. Specify the correct `Content-Type`.

```
fetch('http://localhost/test.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        test: 'test'
    })
})
```

## PHP won't process JSON formatted requests automatically

You need to read the raw body and parse it yourself. This is a FAQ. Here is [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369/19068).

Comment: I don't need to use JSON. I can use only `$_POST['test']` but I found this method. Can I remove JSON.stringify?

Comment: Not unless you replace it with something to convert the object to the data format you want to use instead

Comment: OK. I do that and I see In chrome (tab network), that response is correctly but in the console I have this error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: `print_r` doesn't output JSON

Comment: No. I commented print_r (I have only `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` in my php file)  and I have this same error. Could you show my correctly code?

Comment: So now you're outputting **nothing**. Trying to parse nothing as JSON will throw an error because "nothing" isn't JSON.

Comment: OK. But if I good understand this code decode all POST request from json? So how can I return that console.log could print that?

Comment: `print` some JSON.